# $\lVert f \rVert_\infty$ for functions with a singularity

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I have a question on terminology: A lecture I'm following uses $C[a, b]$ to denote the vector space of real-valued functions that are continuous on $[a, b]$. For functions in these vector spaces it also defines the norm:

$$
\lVert f \rVert_\infty = \max_{x \in [a, b]}|f(x)|
$$

Now, what if e.g. we have $a = 0, b = 1$ and $f(x) = 1/x$? Is $f \in C[0, 1]$ and if so, is it meaningful to say that $\lVert f \rVert = \infty$?

Comment: You tell me. Is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ continuous (from the right) at the origin?

Comment: $f = 1/x$ is not even _defined_ at $x=0$. By the way, continuous functions on a compact space like $[0,1]$ are bounded

Comment: @KennyWong Yeah, that figures, so my question does not really make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your lecturer writes the definition
$$
\lVert f \rVert_\infty = \max_{x \in [a, b]}|f(x)|,
$$
it is implicit that $f$ is bounded on $[a, b]$, and attains its bounds. In other words, it is implicit that there exists a $c \in [a, b]$ such that $|f(x)| \leq |f(c)|$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. $\lVert f \rVert_\infty $ is then defined to be $|f(c)|$.

The Extreme Value Theorem says that all continuous functions on *compact* spaces are bounded and attain their bounds. $[a, b]$ is compact by the Heine-Borel theorem, so the Extreme Value Theorem applies to $[a, b]$.

So you're never going to run into problems applying this definition - certainly not problems of the kind that you mention in your original post where $f$ is unbounded.

Your example of $f(x) = 1/x$ doesn't work because this $f$ is not defined at $x = 0$, and therefore is not a function on $[0, 1]$.